# Word mail merge - Keep lines together lines are not staying together

Tags: ms-word, docx-mailmerge

I have a Word mail merge documnet which gets data from a C# application.  The document contains a table of data which can grow to multiple pages.  After the definition of the table, I have a bunch of lines of text.  I need to make sure that all these lines of text are always grouped together.  If Word cant fit them all on the current page, then I need Word to bump to a new page and have all the lines printed on the new page.

In the merge document, I highlight the 6 lines and right click and select Paragraph. I then click on the Line and Page Breaks tab and I click in the Keep lines together check box.  At this point, Word places black squares next to the lines I want grouped.  The page looks like this:

[image]

However, when I run my application and generate the document, Word ends up putting some of the lines on 1 page and the remaining lines on another.

Is there some other flag or switch that I need to set to have Word properly keep these lines together on one page?